# Who said the following

Tags: bible

American King James Version
For the wages of sin is death; but the gift of God is eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord.Was it God who said this?

Comment: The quote is from Paul's letter to the Romans:  Chapter 6, verse 23.

Answer (score 2):

The author of the letter written to the Christians in Rome is identified in the opening words:

> Paul, a servant of Christ Jesus, called to be an apostle, set apart for the gospel of God...

Paul became a Christian after he met with the resurrected Christ Jesus who commissioned him to take the good news of the gospel to the nations. His words were spoken and written under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit.  God used Paul as His mouthpiece, as God has done with all the authors of the Holy Bible.

2 Timothy 3:16 says this about the Bible:

> All Scripture is breathed out by God and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness...

At the time of writing (between A.D. 56 to 58) Paul, a Roman citizen, had not yet visited the church in Rome.  He dictated his letter to a Christian named  Tertius, as confirmed in Romans 16:22:

> I Tertius, who wrote this letter, greet you in the Lord.